# Not receiving Compact Block even after 'sendcompact' message

Tags: address-generation, regtest, compact-blocks

I have setup a regtest net locally with 2 nodes. One of nodes generates blocks using 'bitcoin-cli generatetoaddress 10 ', sendcompact message was sent from other node yet it gets normal block(NetMsgType::BLOCK) instead of compact block(NetMsgType::CMPCTBLOCK). As per protocol documentation, 'sendcmpct' should change btc node state to send compact block. Am I misunderstanding this flow? Kindly point to resource on how to generate compact block on regtest net setup.